# How to check if element is visible or not

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Need your help wanted to check if particular element is visible or not.
in the below code I have passed wrong ID so that system will throw `NoSuchElementException` in the case of correct element it is giving correct answer. But in the case of wrong element it is throwing exception instead of handling it.

Please help in this -

```
package com;

import java.util.NoSuchElementException;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import org.testng.asserts.SoftAssert;

public class Windowgoogle {
    static WebDriver driver;
    static String baseUrl="http:/www.google.co.in";

    @Test
    public void openBrowser()
    {
    driver=new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get(baseUrl);

        System.out.println(existsElement("qo"));//Adding Invalid ID
    }   

        private boolean existsElement(String id) 
        {
            boolean chk = false;
            try {

                    chk=driver.findElement(By.name(id)).isDisplayed();
                    return chk;
                }  catch (NoSuchElementException e)
                    {
                    return false;//Control should go to catch but exception is not getting handled properly.
                    }



        }



}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have imported wrong NoSuchElementException. You should have imported

> org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException

instead of `java.util.NoSuchElementException`

Comment: Thanks Vivek...Can you also help me in the script for file uplaod using sendkeys. .I asked this question in this URL.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28559798/sample-script-for-upload-file-using-sendkeys?noredirect=1#comment45490449_28559798

Comment: A solution was already provided to u in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28392931/not-able-to-upload-file-using-robot-class-and-sendkeys) post.

Comment: Hi Vivek,
I Believe you can help in this Problem.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28487624/getting-error-while-running-test-suite

See if you can help me in this....Please

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you are able to use driver.findElements as a way to determine if the element is present on the page without using the NoSuchElementException.

For this you would use:

```
private boolean existsElement(String id) {
    return !driver.findElements(By.name(id)).isEmpty();
}
```

When the method findElements cannot find any elements that match the specified locator, it returns an empty list. It is a very common alternative to catching the NoSuchElementException.

Answer (score 1):

While catching `NoSuchElementException` works, it's not an elegant solution. Imagine if you have to have this logic in multiple places. The code will be bloated and hard to maintain. You can use helper methods from [ExpectedConditions](https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html) class. This is how you would use it,

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,30);

boolean isNotVisible = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("foo")));

if(isNotVisible) {
   // do stuff
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;
import org.openqa.selenium.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import org.testng.asserts.SoftAssert;
public class dropdown {
     private static WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver() ;
     String Path ="C:\\Users\\VGupta\\Desktop\\testcases\\auto.xlsx";
     @Test
     public void test() throws Exception
    {
            driver.get("http://www.test.com/");
          //Dimension size   = ('900','500');
          driver.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(1000,1000));
         try{
         driver.findElement(By.id("foo")).click();

          } catch(NoSuchElementException e)
          {
              System.out.println(e.getStackTrace());
          }
}
```